# I can't figure out how to indent using printf

Tags: java

I am currently learning Java and am having trouble with some code

I tried messing around with the syntax of it but I have no idea.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%14s%n", "Location: Key West, Florida");
  }
}
```

I want it to indent but nothing is happening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align printf output in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961130/align-printf-output-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `%14s` assigns a space of 14 character and your string is longer than that so it seems as no effect.
If you want to see the effect try

```
System.out.printf("%34s%n", "Location: Key West, Florida");
```

It will give a space of 34 character and **Right - Indent** your string.
If you want a **Left - Indent** add a `-` before the size of formatting.

```
System.out.printf("%-34s%n", "Location: Key West, Florida");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `\t` character to add the tab-space character to a printed string. e.g.

```
 System.out.printf("\t%s", "public class Test {\n \t\tSystem.our.println(\"it works fine\");\n \t}");
```

OUTPUT:

```
public class Test {
    System.our.println("it works fine");
}
```

Comment: Adding a bunch of `\t`s probably isn't an ideal solution to the problem at hand